# Return JSON from MVC via AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I've been using a hard coded JSON object:

```
var resuts = [{id: 1, Code: "Code A"}, {id: 2, Code: "Code B"}]
```

I'm then iterating this object calling the items by index and using .length:

```
for (var i = 0; i < resuts.length; i++) {
            console.log('id:' + resuts[i].id +  ' | ' + 'Code:' + resuts[i].Code}
```

Now I want to pull this data from the server so I created an object to handle the properties and have this action method:

```
public ActionResult GetResults()
{
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            results = new List<Question>()
            {
                new Question { id = 1, Code = "Code A},
                new Question { id = 1, Code = "Code B}
            }
        });

        return Json(new { data = json }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm calling it with this AJAX:

```
function GetResultsJSON() {    
        $.ajax({        
            type: 'GET',        
            url: '/Home/GetResults/',
            dataType: 'json',  
            traditional: true,     
            success: function (data) {            
                results = data;
            },        
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Error.');
            }
        })
 };
```

Now my results object contains:

```
"{" results ":[{" id ":1," Code ":" Code A "},{" id ":1," Code ":" Code B "}]}"
```

Now I get JavaScript errors when trying to use the length property or call items by index.  From what I have read up on, I think my original hard coded object is just an array, however, I have to work differently with the JSON that's returned from my controller.

Can anyone advise on either returning the array format that I was originally working with or the best way to handle the JSON format as it's returned here?  I have tried things like

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
alert(obj.name);
});
```

but this returns undefined.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public JsonResult TestAjax(int leagueId)
    {

         var results = new List<BaseballViewModel>()
        {
            new BaseballViewModel{ DivisionId = 1},
            new BaseballViewModel{ DivisionId = 2}
        }.ToList();

         return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
    }

$.ajax({
            url: "/Home/TestAjax",
            type: "GET",
            data: { leagueId: 5 },
            success: function (data) {

             // alert(JSON.stringify(data)); show entire object in JSON format
                $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                    alert(obj.DivisionId);
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I altered my controller to return a List<Question> which returns 'Object { id=1, Code="Code A" }' and allows me to iterate the JS array by index and .length etc.  Creating an IEnumerable seemed to return a collection of each IEnumerable which seemed to change the format of the resulting JSON, I only needed one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
    alert(obj.name);
});
```

why don't you try:

```
$.each(data.results, function(i, obj) {
    alert(obj.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Model class that way :

```
[Serializable()]
public class MyResponse
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Code {get; set;}

}
```

And that you create a list of "MyResponse"

You will just have to do

```
return Json(new { data = listOfMyResponse}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Maybe the list won't be serializable and you will have to use a table of MyResponse